# Removing Stop Word From a Text in Python Without Using NLTK

Tags: python, list, stop-words

I made a list of stopwords in my native language in Python. How can I remove them without using NLTK when I type a text ?

Comment: You need to have all the stop words stored in a text file. Look for each word from text file in your text. If found, delete it from your text.

Comment: The approach is going to differ depending on the orthography of the language. Can you please add the language to the question itself?

Comment: Language is Turkish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this out (This only works if the language in question can be broken on spaces, but that hasn't been clarified – Thanks to Oso) :

```
import numpy as np
your_stop_words = ['something','sth_else','and ...']
new_string = input()
words = np.array(new_string.split())
is_stop_word = np.isin(words,your_stop_words)
filtered_words = words[~is_stop_word]
clean_text = ' '.join(filtered_words)
```

If the language in question can not be broken to spaces, you can use this solution :

```
your_stop_words = ['something','sth_else','and ...']
new_string = input()
clean_text = new_string
for stop_word in your_stop_words :
    clean_text = clean_text.replace(stop_word,"")
```

In this case, you need to ensure that a stop word can not be a part of another word. you can do it based on your language. for example you can use spaces around your stop words.

Comment: This only works if the language in question can be broken on spaces, but that hasn't been clarified

Comment: Thanks. Can you explain what is "numpy"? I am new at Python.

Comment: @Oso , Yes you are right. I edited my answer based on your comment. Thank you.

Comment: @FranklinHudson , Check this [link](https://www.w3schools.com/python/numpy_intro.asp#:~:text=NumPy%20is%20a%20Python%20library,NumPy%20stands%20for%20Numerical%20Python)

Comment: I take the Process finished with exit code 0 fail with this code.

Comment: @FranklinHudson I need more details.

Comment: I solved the problem for now thanks a lot. Do you have Instagram or Email adress? To contact with you?

Comment: @FranklinHudson you can find me [here](https://behzadshayegh.github.io/).